# MongoDB - Can I use @TextIndexed and @Indexed on a field at the same time?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-indexes

Is it possible to have both index and text index on the same column in MongoDB?

I want to query `Question` collection by country code (i.e. "US") and unwind related data in `Country` collection by country code as id.

Example code for Spring Data MongoDB / Kotlin:

```
@Document
data class Question(
    @Id val id: String,

    @TextIndexed
    @Indexed(name = "question_country_code_index")
    val countryCode: String
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to apply both annotation to the very same property. The `IndexResolver` will then create two indexes.

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "Question_TextIndex",
    "ns" : "db.question",
    "weights" : {
        "textIndexedPropertyWithDefaultWeight" : 1
    },
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "countryCode" : 1
    },
    "name" : "question_country_code_index",
    "ns" : "db.question",
    "collation" : {
        ...
    }
}
```